# Website viewed with electron unable to load all resources

Tags: electron

I am trying to load https://trello.com with `win.loadURL('https://trello.com');` This works fine but the login page says

```
Your browser was unable to load all of Trello's resources. They may have been blocked by your firewall, proxy or browser configuration.

Try refreshing the page and if that doesn't work, check out our troubleshooting guide.
```

I have tried:

- allowRunningInsecureContent: true
- webSecurity: false
- 'Content-Security-Policy': '*'
- Changing my useragent

Nothing shows up in console and it seems to work fine when i use the < webview > tag.
According to a Trello article the urls that it tries to load resources from are: **d78fikflryjgj.cloudfront.net**, **d2k1ftgv7pobq7.cloudfront.net** or **a.trellocdn.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: true
    }
  })
```

Add this `contextIsolation:true` When you are creating new BrowserWindow